# How do you add the play icon & length indicator to an MPMoviePlayerController frame thumbnail?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, thumbnails

Here's one I haven't been able to find an answer to.  I am creating an iPhone (iOS 5.0) app and have used MPMoviePlayerController to get a thumbnail frame for video clips which I display in a gallery that contains thumbnails for both images & videos (just like the Photos app).

In the Photos app, for video thumbnails, it shows a little toolbar with a movie camera icon and the length of the clip, to indicate the thumbnail is a video. I can't figure out how to add this to my video frame thumbnails.  Do I have to create something like that toolbar and add it to the UIImage of the frame thumbnail myself, or is there something here that I've just missed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking on how to get that information (play length) or are you asking on how to create a complete composited image containing video thumbnail, play length and play button?

Answer (score 1):

I get the solution for your question...
So , you can use this: `

```
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[self getVideoThumbnail:urlFromVideo] 
                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:yourImageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`
```

Function to getThumbnail is here:

```
   - (UIImage *)getVideoThumbnail:(NSURL *)videoURL
   {    
       MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]  initWithContentURL:videoURL];
       UIImage *thumbnail = [player thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0               timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
       //Player autoplays audio on init
       [player stop];
       return thumbnail;
   }
```

I think this is the option for you...